# add Value in file with value of output generated with script

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, gawk

I have a txt/log file which has data-  `cat sample.log/(.txt)`

```
500,3,2
```

there is script running which overwrite the value in sample.log.
Instead of overwrite/or generating a new line I want the data to be get sum up with its respective row.

Example:

```
Sample.log -500,3,1  
Script out- 600,4,3
```

Final output that needs to be stored in `sample.log`

```
1100,7,4
```

Every time the script run it keeps on adding the respective value.

Please help me to get this output.

Comment: Is it the value `-500` in sample.log or this is typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do it using GNU awk where the script is called `script.sh` and the existing total file is called `/tmp/sample.log`:

```
script.sh|\
cat /tmp/sample.log -|\
awk -F, '{for (f=1;f<=NF;f++) TOT[f]+=$f} END {for (f=1;f<length(TOT);f++) printf TOT[f]","; print TOT[length(TOT)]}' >/tmp/sample1.log
mv -f /tmp/sample1.log /tmp/sample.log
```

The output from `script.sh` is combined (put as a line under) the existing `sample.log` and these two lines are then summed in `awk` and the result used to replace `sample.log`

This will work with any number of fields (don't have to be consistent). The delimiter is set to be a comma but this could easily be changed.

Comment: You do not need `cat`, sample `awk '{}' filename` do the same

Comment: `cat` is to combine the output from the script and the file so in this case just using `awk '{}' filename` does not do the same

Comment: Thanks It is working!! but one issue is when we use mv command it pops us to overwrite it ....  mv: overwrite .... How to always put this as yes.

Comment: @gogoud, in OP questions is: " script running which overwrite the value in sample.log" So script is executed independently and create the log, not send info to STDOUT.

Comment: @Amit10504, use `mv -f`

Comment: I've edited it to use mv -f as suggested by Romeo Ninov

Comment: Got it.... mv -f will force to overwrite without any pop up....

Comment: if you are happy with it, please mark it as accepted, thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot guys... !!!! You made my day... Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Tried with below steps

```
sh script >scriptout
cat sample.log scriptout|awk -F ","  'BEGIN{sum=0;kum=0;jum=0} OFS =","{sum=sum+$1}{kum=kum+$2}{jum=jum+$3}END{print sum,kum,jum}' > final_out
mv final_out sample.log
```